# Migrate from InfluxCloud

Tags: influxdb

What would be the best approach to migrate FROM InfluxCloud to my own InfluxDB Instance.

Obviously, the influxd backup/restore functionality would be perfect, but that one does not work on InfluxCloud as stated on their [documentation](https://help.influxcloud.net/tips_and_faqs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently had to do something similar and used the following approach.

1. Use a CURL request to output the collection in a json file

   ```
   curl "https://CLOUD-ENDPOINT.influxcloud.net:8086/db/DATABASE_NAME/series?u=USERNAME&p=PASSWORD&q=select%20*%20from%20DATABASE_NAME%3B" > output.json
   ```

   Replace CLOUD_ENDPOINT, DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME and PASSWORD with the correct values.
2. Convert the json file to Line protocol. There already exist a lot of scripts for this. Example: [influx-json2line](https://github.com/airyland/influx-json2line)
3. Use [influx CLI](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/tools/shell/#influx-arguments) to import the file again.